# Having Dialogbox call itself causes checkboxes to go blank vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dialog

I'm converting a table top cardgame to computer. When someone attacks someone who has a dodge/block/disarm(if atked via weapon) then the defender has a chance to avoid taking damage from the attack. This part works fine!

If the defender is attacked with a "Spinning backfist" or "Roundhouse kick" then the attack is suppose bounce to a player right next to the defender. The player the attacked is bounced to is suppose to be a player of the original defenders choice (has to be a player next to them). This part works as well.

The problem I have is, if the next defender has a "Dodge" card then they are suppose to be given the same option of bounce the attack to a player next to them.

My method for accomplishing this is using an use case to target the new corresponding player and if the dodge cards in their inventory is > 0 then I use the call function to recall the load function starting the process all over again. After doing so however upon load the checkboxes completely disappear.

I added a couple labels to help find where the code may be going wrong. I know the load procedure works. It is somewhere in the "calculateload procedure that seems to be doing this.

I have listed the entire code for the dodgeblockdisarm dialogbox.
The load function is a little over half way through.

```
Public Class DodgeBlockDisarmDialog
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim Rnd As Random
    Public DiscardWeapon As Boolean
    Public PlayerTemp As Integer
    Public MultipleExecutionBoolean As Boolean = False



    Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
        Dim String1 As String = ""
        Dim String2 As String = ""
        Dim IDBuster, SelectPlayer, PlayerCardsInteger, Number As Integer
        Dim CardsA As Integer = LunchMoneyMainForm.T * 5
        Dim CardsB As Integer = 5 * LunchMoneyMainForm.T + 4

        Dim CheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {AvoidCheckBox, AvoidCheckBox2, AvoidCheckBox3, AvoidCheckBox4, AvoidCheckBox5}

        For PlayerCardsInteger = CardsA To CardsB
            Dim TextConverInteger As Integer = PlayerCardsInteger Mod 5

            'Choose player and select specific cards
            Select Case LunchMoneyMainForm.T
                Case 0
                    SelectPlayer = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger
                    IDBuster = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).ID
                Case 1
                    SelectPlayer = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger2
                    IDBuster = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).ID
                Case 2
                    SelectPlayer = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger3
                    IDBuster = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).ID
                Case 3
                    SelectPlayer = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger4
                    IDBuster = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).ID
                Case 4
                    SelectPlayer = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger5
                    IDBuster = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).ID
            End Select
            If CheckBoxArray(TextConverInteger).Checked = True AndAlso (IDBuster = 14 Or IDBuster = 17 Or (IDBuster = 16 And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                           LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11))) Then
                'Set NoHPLoss to 0

                LunchMoneyMainForm.NoHPLoss = 0
                'Subtract cards from defender's deck
                Select Case LunchMoneyMainForm.T
                    Case 0
                        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger -= 1
                    Case 1
                        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger2 -= 1
                    Case 2
                        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger3 -= 1
                    Case 3
                        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger4 -= 1
                    Case 4
                        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger)).QuantityInteger5 -= 1
                End Select

                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.DeckGroup Where r.QuantityInteger > 0 Select r

                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)

                    LunchMoneyMainForm.DeckGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
                    'Select the Player depending value of T
                    Select Case LunchMoneyMainForm.T
                        Case 0
                            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
                        Case 1
                            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 += 1
                        Case 2
                            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3 += 1
                        Case 3
                            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 += 1
                        Case 4
                            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 += 1
                    End Select

                    LunchMoneyMainForm.CardTypeArray(PlayerCardsInteger) = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardType
                    CheckBoxArray(TextConverInteger).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(PlayerCardsInteger) = Number
                End If

                If CheckBoxArray(TextConverInteger).Checked = True And IDBuster = 17 And LunchMoneyMainForm.CounterTrueFalse = True Then
                    Select Case LunchMoneyMainForm.T
                        Case 0
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
                            String1 = "Player 2"
                            String2 = "Player 5"
                        Case 1
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = False
                            String1 = "Player 1"
                            String2 = "Player 3"
                        Case 2
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = False
                            String1 = "Player 2"
                            String2 = "Player 4"
                        Case 3
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = True
                            String1 = "Player 3"
                            String2 = "Player 5"
                        Case 4
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player1.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player2.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player3.Enabled = False
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player4.Enabled = True
                            AtkPlayerDialog.Player5.Enabled = False
                            String1 = "Player 1"
                            String2 = "Player 4"
                    End Select
                    AtkPlayerDialog.RoundFistLabel.Text = "Attack " & String1 & " or " & String2 & "!"
                    AtkPlayerDialog.ShowDialog()

                    LunchMoneyMainForm.N = AtkPlayerDialog.DialogResult


                    'if attacked player has a dodge or block card, then open dodge/block dialog
                    Select Case (LunchMoneyMainForm.N)
                        Case 1
                            If LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger > 0 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger > 0 Then
                                MultipleExecutionBoolean = True
                                OK_Button.Visible = False
                                Call DodgeBlockDialog_Load(sender, e)
                                testerslabel.Text = "1"
                            End If
                        Case 2
                            If LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger2 > 0 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger2 > 0 Then
                                MultipleExecutionBoolean = True
                                Call DodgeBlockDialog_Load(sender, e)
                                testerslabel.Text = "2"
                            End If
                        Case 3
                            If LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger3 > 0 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger3 > 0 Then
                                MultipleExecutionBoolean = True
                                Call DodgeBlockDialog_Load(sender, e)
                                testerslabel.Text = "3"
                            End If
                        Case 4
                            If LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger4 > 0 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger4 > 0 Then
                                MultipleExecutionBoolean = True
                                Call DodgeBlockDialog_Load(sender, e)
                                testerslabel.Text = "4"
                            End If
                        Case 5
                            If LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(14).QuantityInteger5 > 0 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(17).QuantityInteger5 > 0 Then
                                MultipleExecutionBoolean = True
                                Call DodgeBlockDialog_Load(sender, e)
                                testerslabel.Text = "5"
                            End If
                    End Select




                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(LunchMoneyMainForm.N).HitPoints -= LunchMoneyMainForm.TempDamageStorage
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.TempDamageStorage = 0

                    AtkPlayerDialog.RoundFistLabel.Visible = False

                    LunchMoneyMainForm.HitPoints1.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(1).HitPoints.ToString
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.HitPoints2.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(2).HitPoints.ToString
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.HitPoints3.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(3).HitPoints.ToString
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.HitPoints4.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(4).HitPoints.ToString
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.HitPoints5.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(5).HitPoints.ToString


                    LunchMoneyMainForm.CounterTrueFalse = False
                End If
                If LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 OrElse LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 OrElse LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 OrElse LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11 Then
                    DiscardWeapon = True
                End If
            End If
            CheckBoxArray(TextConverInteger).Checked = False
        Next PlayerCardsInteger


        LunchMoneyMainForm.T = PlayerTemp

        If MultipleExecutionBoolean = False Then
            Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel_Button.Click
        Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        LunchMoneyMainForm.T = PlayerTemp
    End Sub

    Private Sub DodgeBlockDialog_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        OK_Button.Enabled = False
        Dim CheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {AvoidCheckBox, AvoidCheckBox2, AvoidCheckBox3, AvoidCheckBox4, AvoidCheckBox5}

        'show player number on load
        PlayerLabel.Text = "Player " & LunchMoneyMainForm.N

        'store attackers value of T so the defender can retaliate
        If MultipleExecutionBoolean = False Then
            PlayerTemp = LunchMoneyMainForm.T
            LunchMoneyMainForm.T = (LunchMoneyMainForm.N - 1)
        Else
            LunchMoneyMainForm.T = (LunchMoneyMainForm.N - 1)
            TLabel.Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.T.ToString
        End If

        Call CalculateLoad()
    End Sub
    Private Sub CalculateLoad()
        Dim roll As Integer
        Dim CheckBoxArray() As CheckBox = {AvoidCheckBox, AvoidCheckBox2, AvoidCheckBox3, AvoidCheckBox4, AvoidCheckBox5}
        'Player1
        If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 0 Then
            For roll = 0 To 4
                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup Where r.QuantityInteger > 0 Select r
                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
                    CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                End If
            Next roll
            For roll = 0 To 4
                Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
                LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1

            Next


        End If
        'player2
        If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 1 Then
            For roll = 5 To 9
                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup Where r.QuantityInteger2 > 0 Select r
                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
                    Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 -= 1
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
                    CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                End If
            Next roll
            For roll = 5 To 9
                Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
                LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger2 += 1

            Next

        End If
        'player3
        If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 2 Then
            For roll = 10 To 14
                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup Where r.QuantityInteger3 > 0 Select r
                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
                    Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger3 -= 1
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
                    CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                End If
            Next roll
            For roll = 10 To 14
                Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
                LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1

            Next

        End If

        'player4
        If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 3 Then
            For roll = 15 To 19
                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup Where r.QuantityInteger4 > 0 Select r
                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
                    Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 -= 1
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
                    CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                End If
            Next roll
            For roll = 15 To 19
                Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
                LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger4 += 1

            Next

        End If
        'player5
        If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 4 Then
            For roll = 20 To 24
                Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyGame.LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup Where r.QuantityInteger5 > 0 Select r
                If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
                    Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 -= 1
                    LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
                    CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
                End If
            Next roll
            For roll = 20 To 24
                Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
                LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger5 += 1

            Next

        End If

        'Make checkboxes visible if Dodge or Block, or Disarm(if weapon) card are in the inventory


        If CheckBoxArray(0).Text = "Dodge" Or CheckBoxArray(0).Text = "Block" Or (CheckBoxArray(0).Text = "Disarm" And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                     LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11)) Then
            CheckBoxArray(0).Visible = True
        End If
        If CheckBoxArray(1).Text = "Dodge" Or CheckBoxArray(1).Text = "Block" Or (CheckBoxArray(1).Text = "Disarm" And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                     LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11)) Then
            CheckBoxArray(1).Visible = True
        End If
        If CheckBoxArray(2).Text = "Dodge" Or CheckBoxArray(2).Text = "Block" Or (CheckBoxArray(2).Text = "Disarm" And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                     LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11)) Then
            CheckBoxArray(2).Visible = True
        End If
        If CheckBoxArray(3).Text = "Dodge" Or CheckBoxArray(3).Text = "Block" Or (CheckBoxArray(3).Text = "Disarm" And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                     LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11)) Then
            CheckBoxArray(3).Visible = True
        End If
        If CheckBoxArray(4).Text = "Dodge" Or CheckBoxArray(4).Text = "Block" Or (CheckBoxArray(4).Text = "Disarm" And (LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 8 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 9 Or _
                                                                                                                                     LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 10 Or LunchMoneyMainForm.IDbuster = 11)) Then
            CheckBoxArray(4).Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You are handling your code inside the event thread and in it you´re invoking the same function. First you're not supposed to be calling the load method directly like you are, secondly start using background threads.

Comment: I'm new to this in General. Is there a good explanation  to back-ground threading?

Comment: I'll give you a brief. There is only one thread managing all UI events and that includes the rendering. The load method is raised as a system events, as such, if you do any long operation within that method the whole UI is left in a state of no responsiveness. In you program you do that and you also have a recurring function without a guard clause, when  you call the load method inside the same method. As for the thread, look at this simple provider: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker